# IIRF on IIS 6 Rejects Server Connections

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis-6, redirect, rewrite

My clients have two sites (call them, say, `mainsite` and `subsite`) that are run as subscription services. They want clients to be able to access `subsite` only if they've got a paid subscription on their main site, so anyone accessing `subsite` directly or not through `mainsite` should get redirected to `mainsite` (to buy a subscription).

I've been tasked with handling this redirection, and since their servers are running on Windows Server 2003 with IIS 6, I installed IIRF (Ionic ISAPI Rewrite Filter) on the `subsite` server to handle rewrites and redirects. The `subsite` Iirf.ini file contains the following:

```
# Enable logging.
RewriteLogLevel 1
RewriteLog D:\sites\subsite\Files\IIRFLog

# Enable services.
RewriteEngine ON
StatusInquiry ON
IterationLimit 5

# Redirect to main site.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERRER} ^https?://(?!mainsite)([-\w]*\.)(?!mainsite)\S*$ [I]
RedirectRule ^(.*)$ http://mainsite.com/

# Add `www.` to URLs.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(subsite\.com).*$ [I]
RedirectRule ^/(.*)$ http://www.subsite.com/$1 [I,R=301]

# URL rewrites for WordPress pretty permalinks.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

(Of course, `mainsite` and `subsite` are substituted for real domains.)

The problem is, however, that when I enable IIRF on the server, it completely stops serving pages (in Firefox, the error given is that the server reset the connection). No redirects happen, and no log files are written to the given log file location.

The configuration is completely valid according to the bundled `TestDriver` and `TestParse` programs, so what might be going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that while our server runs on the 64-bit version of Windows Server, our IIS installation is running in 32-bit mode. Running through the Windows Event Log revealed that we had the 64-bit version of IIRF. The 32-bit version wouldn't install  on our server (sensibly enough), so a manual installation got it to work.